# Start several fish shells in different directories?

Tags: shell, fish

In order to be able to launch my work environment with a single command, I want to start several `urxvt` windows running `fish` shell in different folders. However, I found no obvious way of having `fish` run a startup command (e.g. a `cd`) and not exit afterwards. Has anyone figured out how to do start `fish` in a particular directory without making it a default in `config.fish`?

Comment: Do the `cd` before starting `fish` (`cd /x && urxvt`)

Comment: urxvt always seems to start in my home dir.

Answer (score 4):

Run `cd` from whatever is calling fish. For example, instead of `urxvt -e fish`, run

```
urxvt -e sh -c 'cd /wherever/you/want; fish'
```

Make that `urxvt -e sh -c 'cd /wherever/you/want && fish'` if you don't want the terminal to open if the directory doesn't exist.

Comment: This works for GNU screen configs as well, example in `.screenrc` : `screen -t Projects  1 sh -c 'cd /home/my/projects/dir && fish'`

Answer (score 0):

For as long as I've been on StackExchange, I've been haunted by this problem where, as soon as I take the time to write up a question, I miraculously come across the answer.

For anyone who's trying to do the same, here's what I ended up doing.

If I add the following at the top of my **config.fish**:

```
cd $FISH_START_DIR
```

then I can do what I wanted to with the following command line:

```
$ urxvt -e /bin/bash -c 'FISH_START_DIR=<my required directory> fish'
```

*Hacky, yes, but works a charm.

  Sorry for the false alarm.*

Comment: You don't want to do that. config.fish is interpreted by all the fish shells including those that interpret fish scripts or `fish -c ...`. `urxvt` won't change the current directory. You probably have something wrong in your setup (for instance a `cd` alone or `cd $unsetvar` in your config.fish).

Comment: That line is the only thing that I currently have in `config.fish`. If FISH_START_DIR is unset, fish just starts in my home folder as usual, which is enough for the time being.